# how to get all the multi valued attributes into a csv file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a sample data as below .Below attributes are belong to [data] dictionary.   In "XXXX" i have value "Naveen" and in "YYYYY" i have "Kumar" and "Rajesh" . i am trying with the below code to get 2 recorded output

Please help with any suggestion

```
    {
  "data": [
  {
      "Empid": "1234",
      "Empname": "ABC",
       "data1": {
          "XXXX": [
            {
              "relative": {
                "id": "Naveen"
              }
            }
          ],
          "YYYYY": [
            {
              "relative": {
                "id": "Kumar"
              }
            },
            {
              "relative": {
                "id": "Rajesh"
              }
            }
          ]
          }

     }
     ]
}
```

Please find below code ( i am trying )

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(json_file['data'])):
    temp = {}
    temp['Empid'] = json_file['data'][i]['Empid']
    temp['EmpName'] = json_file['data'][i]['EmpName']
        for key in json_file['data'][i]['data1'].keys():
                try:
                    for j in range(len(json_file['data'][i]['data1'][key])):
                        temp[key]  = json_file['data'][i]['data1'][key][j]['relative']['id'] 
                except:
                    temp[key] = None                    
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([temp])
        df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], sort=True)
```

Final output i am trying to achieve

```
 EmpID EmpName XXXX   YYYYY 
 1234  ABC     Naveen  Kumar
 1234  ABC     Nan     Rajesh
```

but i am getting only 1 record

```
 EmpID EmpName XXXX   YYYYY 
 1234  ABC     Naveen  Kumar
```

Please help me with any suggestion

Comment: What is it `['data']` and `['relTo']` ?

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER. Hi Bringer, Added few more detail in the sample record. Sorry for typo.

Comment: Thank you, and you trying to create a csv file with `temp` ?  Can you create a matrix instead of dico ?

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER  Yes bringer. I need to create these data into csv file . Matrix instead of Dico means ..? ( i am totally new to python  please don't mind ).

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER  -- How to create a matrix ... ?

Comment: A dico has a key, and for the key you have value ```{'nom': 'Wayne', 'prenom': 'Bruce'}```
A matrix is just a list in two dimensions ```[[nom,Wayne],[prenom,Bruce]]```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194180/discussion-between-avinash-and-hippolyte-bringer).

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER .. I added complete information of data and code.. Please have a look

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER .. Hi Bringer. Is there any way i can achive,,,

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
key=list(json_file1['data'][0].keys())
df=pd.concat([json_normalize(json_file1['data'][0][key[0]]),json_normalize(json_file1['data'][0][key[1]])],axis=1)
df=df.ffill()
df.columns=key
df


   XXXX    YYYYY
0   Naveen  Kumar
1   Naveen  Rajesh
```

### For automating it , you can iterate over the distinct keys

```
DF={}
key=list(json_file1['data'][0].keys())
for i in range(len(key)):
    df=json_normalize(json_file1['data'][0][key[i]])
    DF[key[i]]=(pd.concat([df],axis=0))
DF1=pd.concat(DF,axis=1)
DF1=DF1.ffill()
DF1.columns=key
DF1
```

#### output

```
   XXXX   YYYYY    ZZZZZ
0   Naveen  Kumar   Kumar1
1   Naveen  Rajesh  Rajesh1
```

Comment: actually i may have "ZZZZ" along with "XXXX" , "YYYY" . I have n number of keys available, but for sample i have provided 2 keys for example. Is there any possibility without specifying keys like 'XXXX' , can i make it generic .. ?

Comment: i have shared the idea to proceed with sample data . It could be replicated for further query. I ll try to have a generic one.Hope you have found this idea useful

Comment: Thanks a  lot for the idea. I am trying this approach and i will update you in few mins. but one issue i have is , as i mentioned i may have "n" number of keys and multiple records for the same key ( as like i have provided example for "YYYYY" ) and i cant specify key[0] and key[1] because for some of the keys i may have 0,1,2 as well.

Comment: I have added to iterate over distinct keys and then concating the results at the end.

Comment: what's the  error , same above code is working for me .

Comment: Actually , i have 2 static columns which are my key columns need to be populated for both the records as i mentioned in the above expected output. But those are not getting populated. Please help me with some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

if you json is like that :

```
json_file = {
  "data": [
     {
          "XXXX": [
            {
              "relative": {
                "id": "Naveen"
              }
            }
          ],
          "YYYYY": [
            {
              "relative": {
                "id": "Kumar"
              }
            },
            {
              "relative": {
                "id": "Rajesh"
              }
            }
          ]
    }
     ]
}
```

The code below put the result in the matrix `temp` :

```
temp = []
for key in json_file['data'][0].keys():
    for i in json_file['data'][0][key]:
        temp.append([key,i['relative']['id']])
```

The result is :

```
[['XXXX', 'Naveen'], ['YYYYY', 'Kumar'], ['YYYYY', 'Rajesh']]
```

Comment: @ Bringer ... Thanks for the reply. But without Matrix , is that possible ... ?

Comment: If you don't want use matrix, I think the better choice is to use DataFrame

Comment: @Bringer. Yes  i am trying the above mentioned code using dataframe only. but ia m unable to get 2 records. I am getting only one record. Please help me how can i try and achieve in dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

An other answer with DataFrame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for key in json_file['data'][0].keys():
    for j in range(len(json_file['data'][0][key])):
        df.loc[j,key] = json_file['data'][0][key][j]['relative']['id']
```

Result :

```
XXXX    YYYYY
0   Naveen  Kumar
1   NaN Rajesh
```

Comment: @Bringer.. It partially worked but i am facing one issue. Other than these keys , i have some other columns which i am reading them manually and assigning them with a sequence order. I have added the code above.  After changing the code in this way , other Main Columns which need to be repeated are going to separate record.

Comment: I am trying to assign these all columns in sequence order. but when i try df.loc. these 2 records are coming as 2 records and other static columns are coming into one record( total it was becoming 3 records )